# Any easy way to tell if mongodb indexes are still being used or not?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

As code for my project is evolving, new indexes are being put in place and I am sure some old ones are no longer necessary. However before I just drop them to see if anything slows down or not, I'd prefer if there is a more programmatic or analytic way to determine if an index is being used any more.

I don't see anything in the system.indexes collection, but ideally there is some stats on index accesses somewhere! Is this the case?

Comment: There isn't a direct metric of per-index usage information (as at MongoDB 2.2.0).  There are several suggestions related to metrics linked to a tracking ticket in the MongoDB issue queue: [SERVER-5828](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5828).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run your `db.collection.find(...)` queries with `.explain()` tacked onto the end. That is the single most useful way to see how queries are running: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain

You can also turn on profiling, and the profile log entries give you index usage for each query profiled. There aren't any aggregate stats, as of yet, though. In particular, it won't give you which indexes aren't being used, only the index that is being used (for each query). (Edit: I must have been imagining that--you have to get the query from the profiler and then run explain on it. Kind of painful manually.) http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler

*Update:*
Just saw this from mongolab; looks like an interesting new project along these lines: http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/06/introducing-dex-the-index-bot/

*Update:*
I created a script to check for indexes that aren't used, via the profiler:
https://github.com/wfreeman/indexalizer

Comment: Dex seems pretty cool but still doesn't let me know which indexes are not used. Gonna check it out though! So it sounds like the way to go i s to profile for a while and then see which indexes never appeared.

Comment: Yeah, profiling is probably your best bet. In fact, I considered writing a tool to do this somewhat automatically--maybe I should break that out again.

Comment: Ok, I spent a couple of hours on a script... seems to work on my fairly simple system. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Awesome writing a script! I also notice you output queries that didn't use an index--neat! Unfortunately the script errors out with explain.cursor has no properties (shell):40

Comment: Hm, I put an extra check to protect against an explain not returning a cursor. See if it works now?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, agreed with other answer, using explain() to queries being executed should give us information, but with latest versions we can try something like :

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { $indexStats: { } } ])
```

Please check below links for more information :

[How do I check if an index is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535439/how-do-i-check-if-an-index-is-being-used)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/#pipe._S_indexStats