# Mongoose, How to know if my queries used indexes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Even using `mongoose.set('debug', true);` does not explain if queries used indexes or not, How can I know if they did?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019313/checking-if-an-index-exists-in-mongodb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an index is being used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535439/how-do-i-check-if-an-index-is-being-used)

Comment: @GillesC That's not what I want, I want something like Mongodb.explain method

Comment: short answer : you can't. long answer, see my link :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use this mongoose plugin [mongoose-explain](https://github.com/vkarpov15/mongoose-explain). If not, then you will have to continue to do `mongoose.set('debug', true);` and copy and paste logged queries to the mongodb shell and issue an `explain()` there.