# How to see which queries are using an index in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I see that an index is being used by MongoDB but I am not sure which queries are using it.

How can I see which queries are using the index?

Edit: To clarify, I want to see *by which queries an index is used*, not the other way around using `explain` to see which indices are used by a specific query.

Comment: do you have an answer for that?

Comment: @AviCohen Yes, somewhat, but it's not straight forward. I ended up looking at the query plan cache of a collection and extracting the index scores, to get some indication of their usage. This requires some scripting to create a statistical analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You can run your query with [.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to find out which index is being used in that particular query.

Eg. with `.find()` you can use `.explain()` like this :

```
db.collection.find().explain()
```

For more information read [MongoDB Explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)

**Edit : Check index used in logs**

To check the which indices are being used in a particular query, you can enable index level logs in mongodb configuration.

From [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/#INDEX)

> **INDEX**
>
> Messages related to indexing operations, such as creating indexes. To
>   specify the log level for INDEX components, set the
>   systemLog.component.index.verbosity parameter.

Enable `systemLog.component.index.verbosity` parameter to enable index logs.

From docs :

> **systemLog.component.index.verbosity Type: integer**
>
> Default: 0
>
> New in version 3.0.
>
> The log message verbosity level for components related to indexing
>   operations. See INDEX components.
>
> The verbosity level can range from 0 to 5:
>
> 0 is the MongoDB’s default log verbosity level, to include
>   Informational messages. 1 to 5 increases the verbosity level to
>   include Debug messages.

Read [MongoDB configuration options - Index verbosity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemLog.component.index.verbosity) for more info.

Comment: I don’t mean a dry run, I want to know historically which queries used an index.

Comment: i think you will have to run the queries with .explain() and then see for yourself

Comment: That is not historic data, I would assume there are logs?

Comment: I don't think an index use is an index operation, the verbosity should be set for the query operation.

Answer (score 2):

In heavy databases, indexes plays an important role.

So, you can run the query by adding `.explain("allPlansExecution")` to your query or clicking on `Explain` in `NoSQLBooster` as shown below.

Run your query with `.explain("allPlansExecution")`: Something like this:

```
db.userdata.find({ "User.CountryID" : 10 })
   .projection({})
   //.sort({_id:-1})
   .limit(10)
   .explain("allPlansExecution")
```

This `.explain("allPlansExecution")` explains you if Index is being used.

**I have explained the JSON as well as the graphical view:**

**1. If you want to check the JSON**, then:

- Run the query with `.explain("allPlansExecution")`, you will get the JSON. If you can see stage as `IXSCAN` the your particular index is being used. but if you are seeing stage as `COLSCAN` (Collection Scan), then index is not used.

  JSON comparison for indexed query and non indexed query:
  [image]
- **Understanding the Schema: [(official link)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)** The basic JSON structure of the `.explain("allPlansExecution")` response is something like this:

  [image]

  **queryPlanner:** MongoDB runs the `query optimizer` to choose the winning plan for the operation under evaluation. queryPlanner explains, which details the query optimizer has selected plan has selected and rejected.

  **executionStats:** MongoDB runs the query optimizer to choose the winning plan, executes the winning plan to completion, and returns statistics describing the execution of the winning plan.

**2. If you are using [NoSQLBooster](https://nosqlbooster.com) for mongoDB.** then just write your query and click on explain, it will show which indexes are being used.

**Index Not Used:**
[image]

**Index Used:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server then one way to get an idea about queries not using indexes is to look at mongodb log file.

Grep "COLLSCAN" from the logs and you get the idea. If indexes are used then the query plan shows "IXSCAN". If it has to scan collection then it shows "COLLSCAN". I've found some slow queries this way. Another symptom of queries not using indexes properly is constant high CPU load on the database server.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the server.